# Google Analytics fetch view I'd using API

Tags: python, google-analytics

I'm trying to build a support analytics tool which will let the end-user to create a dashboard of his own using data from multiple sources, one such source is Google Analytics. I used Google Analytics Core reporting API to fetch the data. However as of now, I'm manually inserting the view I'd of my user account to fetch the data. Since I'm building it for end users, I need to be able to programmatically(using API) to fetch the view i'd of a user account when they are authorizing my app using oauth. I have seen tools like databox which have achieved this so wondering how to replicate the same. Here's the code snippet I'm using

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secrets.json' # Path to client_secrets.json file.
VIEW_ID = 'xxxxxx' #manually inserted view I'd here



def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes the analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', http=http)

  return analytics

def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""

  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print (header + ': ' + dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print ('Date range (' + str(i) + ')')
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print (metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)


def main():

  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. We have to use Management API to fetch all View Id's of a particular account and pass that as a parameter to core reporting api for getting the metrics/dimensions.